# How to check if we are in main thread in kdb/peach

Tags: kdb

Like C++/Java, is there a way to check in Q if current thread is main thread or slave thread? I could not find any reference online about this.

Answer (score 4):

```
q){@[value;"{a::1;`main}[]";`slave]} each 1 2
`main`main
q){@[value;"{a::1;`main}[]";`slave]} peach 1 2
`slave`slave
```

Basically exploit one of the differences in being in a slave thread, you can't set global values. You might also find this [peach/.Q.fc](http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/parallel-peach/) guide useful .Q.fc can be a useful alternative to peach.